# Preventing Android NDK shared library from being lifted

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, apk

My Android app has a Java part and a NDK shared library. I don't want unauthorized people to use the shared library. So what are the ways to prevent other from taking the .so out of the apk file, and then using it in their own app? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only real solution is to not publish the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks but even partial solutions are really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way you can prevent someone from taking .so files out of your apk.

Instead you can **encrypt** your native bridge code and your java source code, to make them almost unreadable.

Make sure you can read the encrypted code, or at least have your own decryption methods.